# Creating second popover within first popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to select the current user when click on the coffee button inside popover. 
Users are populated in the home page.

```
<div class="user">
...
    <div class="popover hovercard" role="tooltip">
        ...
        <div class="info">
            <div class="info-inner">
                <div class="interactions">
                    <a class="coffee-btn btn" href="#">Coffee</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
...
</div>
```

I tried to select the "closest" user but apparently it's targeting all users. 
Below is the JS code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".interactions .coffee-btn" , function(){
        $(this).parents(".popover").popover('hide');

        // get user dom 
        var cur = $(this).closest(".user");
        console.log(cur); //returns an array, not what i want
        cur.css("float", "left");

        // create another popover 

  });
```

Should I assign users an id instead with angular and target them that way?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".interactions .coffee-btn").on("click",  function(){

    // get user dom 
    var cur = $(this).closest(".user");
    console.log(cur); //returns an array, not what i want
    cur.css("float", "left");

});
```

It's working for me [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/z12ysroL/).

When you use `$(this)`, on `(document)`, you're selecting the document, not the button.

Comment: Oh the previous code works for selecting the button. What doesn't work is I'm trying to select the user. So when I console.log(cur), I expect it to return sth like "<div class="user">" but instead it's returning [prevObject: r.fn.init[1]]

Comment: Are you talking about `[div.user, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1]]`? Notice the `div.user`. There is also other properties of that element, so that's why it's present there. If you want it to return something like `<div class="user">`, use pure JS.